# Is having view all option in pagination good in terms of User experience?

Tags: feature-request, ux, users

I have a table which consists of huge data. Users can export these data's to excel. In order to export these data's a user must click on all options and export more than 10 times if currently showing option is set to 10.

Hence, I was planning to have View all in show no.of data's, so that users can have all their data's selected at once and exported easily just with one click.

Is this the best way? If not what are other possible ways to do this action.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'm not sure why you're asking this in Meta, as this seems like a UX question, not a meta question.

Secondly, as you have stated it, your question would be asking for a site review on the UX site - which would get your question closed.  If you change it to be a general question about selecting all elements and exporting, then it will most likely be fine to post on ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Always ensure you are optimizing to the primary use case and ensure your flow supports the side cases.

Is the primary interaction that users will want to always export all table rows and not the viewable table rows? If so, you can have Export the entire table and not need selection. I have a use case like this which I did this design for now. The only thing the export picks up is if any filters have been set up and the UI will only export the total rows returned based on the set of filters, but it doesn't take into account what's viewable. This interaction is optimized to the use case I am working with and users' expectations.

If the primary use case is that users will want to first select which rows want to export, you can handle it as you have proposed which will work but you may want a way for the user to select how many results would want to display if there rae typical expected ranges.

Example:

Display [1-10] [1-50] [1-100] [1-200] [All]

I would definitely recommend to first research how your users are really using the application now based on its limitations and optimize to the majority use case and usage.